# Ubuntu 12.10 not installing?

Tags: installation, 12.10

I had downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 today morning, in torrent form, it was about 700 MB. Than I clicked the setup which is `Wubi.exe´. It completed the downloaded, than It stated "EXPANDING" , It expanded more than 50%, and now it (the progress) has stopped? It's been like 3 hours, and not a single percent has increased? What to do? As I am writing now, it's still showing expanding, Please Help, and by the way, I am new to Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The best is to download it from ubuntu itself: http://www.ubuntu.com/download
If your on a windows machine you can choose the Windows installer. If your on an Ubuntu machine, download the iso file and then there are two options:

1. Burn the .iso to a CD/DVD or
2. use the Startup Disk Creater and create a startup up USB stick.

You can also follow a step by step guide for installing Ubuntu
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest

Cheers,

Erwin

Comment: So, by instead of 'burning' to a disc, can I use Daemon tools?

Comment: Ubuntu no longer fits in a CD. It can be burned either on a DVD, wasting a lot of space. Or a startup USB disk can be created. The later one is a better option, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

For a Wubi-installation (installing Ubuntu IN Windows) you don't have to download 700Mb;
simply download direct the Wubi-installer from the Ubuntu website.

In Windows execute the installer and you Ubuntu-version will be downloaded and installed in Windows. On boot you'll have a text-based option to choose Ubuntu for starting up (or Windows itself).

For setting up a dualboot (Ubuntu side by side with Windows on different partitions) 
you'll need to download your complete Ubuntu-ISO and burn it to a disk (or making a bootable USB-stick). Then you'll have to boot from this burned disk in order to preform an installation.

For detailed instructions or usefull help [click here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/)